# How to run a java jar file with arguments and classpath in command promt

Tags: java, command-line, jar, classpath

I have a jar file program.jar which requires a third party jar external.jar, I can run it with the following command:

```
java -cp -jar program.jar; external.jar
```

But I need to pass two arguments arg1 and arg2 to the program.jar's main function. How can I do it? Without the external.jar I know it can be done with

```
java -jar program.jar arg1 arg2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do the same with the executable JAR.  Its main method should read and process the command line arguments.  I would not leave the -cp value empty like that.  At least add a dot.  Your executable JAR should have all its dependencies packaged inside.

Answer (score 0):

Third Party lib must be in the classpath:

```
java -cp  external.jar -jar program.jar arg1  arg2
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make your jar as executable and execute the main method with arguments as you mentioned above. 
else

> java -cp "<3PPjar files separated by separator>"   args2

Comment: Yes, it works when the main method is executed with the arguments. Appreciate all helps.